# 2 scripts returning 2 different hashes for what i thought was the same string

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm trying to build an MD5 'cracker' and using two different scripts to do it, the first takes a list of words from a wordlist (huge word list.txt), then hashes them and writes them to another file(WordsHash.txt). The second then takes a user defined word, hashes it and compares it to the hashes in WordHash.txt, but i'm getting different hashes for 'the same' string.

first script:

```
import hashlib

hashes = open("WordsHash.txt", 'w')

m = hashlib.md5()

with open("huge word list.txt") as words:
    words = words.readlines()

    print "processing..."

    for line in words:

        line = line.replace("\n", "")

        m.update(line)

        word_hash = m.hexdigest()

        line = "%s %s\n" % (line, word_hash)

        hashes.write(line)

print "done."

hashes.close()
```

and the second script:

```
import hashlib


f = open('WordsHash.txt')

p = '\'due'

password = hashlib.md5()

password.update(p)

password = password.hexdigest()

print "%r %r" %(password, p)



for line in f:

    lines = line.split(" ")

    lines[1] = lines[1].replace("\n", "")

    word_hash = lines[1]

    if word_hash == password:

        print "found it, %s" % line

        exit(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new md5 object for each thing you want to hash. Otherwise, you're are including the previous hashing work when you compute subsequent hashes.

Given the list "apple", "banana", "pear", your processor is giving the hashes for "apple", "applebanana", and "applebananapear".

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that the two pieces of code you gave are the same, you must create a new `hashlib.md5` if you want to hash a new string, otherwise the update will be added to the existing hash instead.

Answer (score 1):

Strip the word before hashing it rather than doing the replace.

```
line = line.strip()
```

Comment: strip() does more than replace \n

Comment: Sure, but telling the asker to strip unconditionally isn't necessarily correct.

Comment: It's been my experience that when hashing words that you generally wish to strip the input to avoid common errors. Most people don't intend to place whitespace before or after the word. This prevents "word" and "word " from hashing differently.